# Sharing a file over whatsapp api

Tags: javascript, api, whatsapp, whatsapi

How can we share a file over WhatsApp from code? Like sharing an image, audio, or a file
For text messages, it is `https://wa.me/<Phone number>?text=Hi`
Is there any API or some other service to send files in JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

The only service I know about is Twilio
https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/api#sending-a-freeform-whatsapp-message-using-the-api